# adding the same number to a list if first element is same python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have lists of data and I want to add the same number to every list if the first element of list is same.

```
for i in range(1,len(file_list)):
    myfiles = open(file_list[i], 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(myfiles)
    allRows = [row for row in reader][1:]

sample_list = [['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', 
'95.3600', '1000', '0'] ['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', 
'95.3600', '1000', '0']['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', 
'105.1300', '1', '0']['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', 
'105.1300', '1', '0']]
```

I want to add same number at the end of list and my actual data should look like

```
actual_list1 = [['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', 
'95.3600', '1000', '0', '1'] ['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', 
'95.3600', '1000', '0', '1']['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', 
'105.1300', '1', '0', '2']['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', 
'105.1300', '1', '0', '2']]
```

Any help Please.

Comment: Write your code in question, not the comment section! And please make a simple and short example of what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use another list ('idx' in my example) to store already-exist 'first element', then assign group number by .index() to get index number of 'first element' in the list

```
sample_list1 = ['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '1000', '0']
sample_list2 = ['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '1000', '0']
sample_list3 = ['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', '105.1300', '1', '0']
sample_list4 = ['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', '105.1300', '1', '0']

lists = [sample_list1, sample_list2, sample_list3, sample_list4]
idx = []
for l in lists:
    if l[0] not in idx:
        idx.append(l[0])
    l.append(f"{idx.index(l[0])}")
    print(l)
```

Result:

```
['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '1000', '0', '0']
['FFC-CJUN', 'D', '20090521', '000000', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '95.3600', '1000', '0', '0']
['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', '105.1300', '1', '0', '1']
['FFC-CJUNW1', 'D', '20100624', '000000', '98.1400', '98.1400', '98.1400', '105.1300', '1', '0', '1']
```

Comment: how to convert this modified list to dataframe?

Comment: simply load the list with pd.DataFrame().  e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns =['col1', 'col2', ... ])`